# Twilio iOS outbound Call disconnect but still showing connected

Tags: ios, react-native, twilio, twilio-programmable-voice

I am using https://github.com/hoxfon/react-native-twilio-programmable-voice in React Native for integrating twilio outbound calls. Calls are working fine, but in iOS when call is cut by the other side, in my app the call is getting terminated but on the top left side there is a green background which appears when a call is in place, it is not getting removed.

I tried the below code, but both deos not help in fixing the issue.

```
await TwilioVoice.disconnect()
await TwilioVoice.unregister()
```

[image]

Comment: The [`disconnect` function](https://github.com/hoxfon/react-native-twilio-programmable-voice/blob/master/ios/RNTwilioVoice/RNTwilioVoice.m#L119-L123) looks like it should call the relevant CallKit methods. Are there any errors? Can you share a bit more of the context? When are you calling `disconnect`/`unregister`? Have you raised this as an issue with the project?

Comment: Have tried calling both disconnect & unregister but it deosn't seems to work. Have called the function when I am getting call_state as 'disconnected' and on componentWillUnmount as well but it didn't work.

The project is not being maintained actively. Have raised another issue already, but didn't get a reply for that.

Comment: It’s a bit difficult as it is a community project, and we don’t know how to support it as Twilio. You might have to dig into the underlying library to work out what is going on.

Comment: Ideally if I am calling from the app with twilio integrated and the call is getting received on the other end. When call is being cut from other, trigger disconnect/unregister should remove the top left green issue??

Comment: Yes, and the Twilio SDK handles that fine normally. It’s hard to tell whether it’s an SDK issue or the React Native wrapper. To me, it looks like you’re calling the right method, you just need to find out where it’s going wrong.